# Extract Day, month and year from date time field

Tags: date, lua

I have a date time filed and I would like to extract day, year and month from it using Lua.

My date field has the values like below and you can see that sting length of each field is different. Is there any function is Lua like oracle ?

- Date

  ```
  9/23/1933 00:00:00 AM
  11/3/2007 00:00:00 AM
  3/3/1987 00:00:00 AM
  ```

Comment: What did you try ? What's not working ? Please post your code

Answer (score 3):

You should read up on pattern matching. Also, you should look to solving things for yourself as much as possible. If you've tried something and it failed, you should document it because sometimes, your code just has an error in it and we can solve it for you quickly. What you're wanting is below, but you can also find a similar example in the [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html) guide (link to direct page, in fact).

```
date_field = "9/3/2007"

month, day, year = string.match(date_field, "(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+)")

print(month, day, year)
```

That will do exactly what you want to do.